# Distributing MongoDB background index creation for single machine MongoDB setup

Tags: mongodb

I have a single machine MongoDB setup which satisfies the needs of my application at runtime but impose a significant bottleneck at the data ingestion time as the background indexing on an array field takes days to complete (inverted index). It seems to be the same issue as posted here [MongoDB large index build very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815863/mongodb-large-index-build-very-slow). I wonder if it makes sense to delegate/distribute index creation and then deploy the result index on the main machine. If anyone considered it - would appreciate sharing the experience. Here are some ideas I wanted to test:

- Use a distributed job like Hadoop or DataFlow to create index tuples , then load them back to either MongoDB directly or another DB that can be more efficient for storing an inverted index.
- Use another service like ElasticSearch that can potentially handle indexing more efficiently; however, I have no experience with it and want to continue hosting everything on the same machine.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets/

Comment: @AlexBlex the solution with replica sets seems to imply multiple servers running the MongoDb. I am happy with a performance of a single machine to serve user requests and looking for the ways to speed up just the inverted index construction time. Also, I don't see how this solution helps to speed up index creation - it still seems to have a single machine responsible to construct the index.

Comment: It's not a solution, it's direction. The question is way to broad to answer. It implies you some kind of batch data import, but I am not going to speculate. Replica set will allow you to index in foreground which is way faster. Anyway you cannot build mongodb index without mongodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I decided to generate all tuples to index with Apache Beam/DataFlow, import all tuples with mongoimport and then create an index on the fields that I need. This way I get an index to query in hours rather than days.